# Validate path variable size

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

I found this example how to validate path variable: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/

```
@PostMapping(value = "/payment/{unique_transaction_id}")
      public ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO> handleWpfMessage(@PathVariable("unique_transaction_id") @Valid @Max(32) String unique_transaction_id) throws Exception {
```

Can I add `@Valid` infant of the limitation for String `@Max(32)` or I have to add `@Validated` at class level as it is shown in the tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define regex for your path variable

`@PostMapping(value = "/payment/{unique_transaction_id:[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,32}}")`

Comment: But should I add @Valid at class level?

Comment: No, not needed, `@Valid` validates all the constraints defined in your request body POJO class.

Comment: Is there other way to apply [a-zA-Z0-9] restriction with annotations?

Comment: I don't think (or I don't know) there exists any annotation for the same purpose. There are other ways like verifying it in a filter / interceptor but it's not straight forward like above solution.

Comment: This might be an enhancement in spring for the same purpose adding a field regex in `@PathVariable` annotation.

Comment: I have one more question. How I can set explicit rule for String to be exactly 32 symbols? For example [a-zA-Z0-9]{32,32} ?

Comment: That will work, but [a-zA-Z0-9]{32} is correct regex. It will match exactly 32 character.